# ChartJS - Correct displayed line chart with not same values for Labels and Dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization, chart.js

I have the following configuration for chart:

Problem is that the documentation is saying:

**There must be one label for each data point.**

But i need to display chart which have:

**561 Labels**

and

**61263 DataSet values**

With the configuration below it produces following result:

[image]

But i would like to display result **like this one**:

[image]

I would like to ask that this is possible to do using the **Chart.js** library or i should to use any other library for data visualisation like **D3.js** or custom solution?

Any example or hint is welcome.

Many thanks for any advice.

```
   var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: $scope.CONST.CHART_TYPE_LINE,
                        data: {
                            xLabels: labelsArr, // VS
                            // Array of the datasets which want to display
                            datasets: [{
                                data: valuesArr,
                                //cubicInterpolationMode:'monotone',
                                //lineTension:0.1,
                                //spanGaps:true,
                                borderColor: "#0000C0",
                                borderWidth: 1,
                                fill: false,
                                steppedLine:true //If true, the line is shown as a stepped line and 'lineTension' will be ignored
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            /*TEST*/
                            scaleOverride: true,
                            scale: 1,
                            scaleSteps:0,
                            scaleStartValue:0,
                            scaleStepWidth:1,
                            /*TEST*/
                            legend: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                                    //display:false, Hide the axis
                                    position: 'bottom',
                                    gridLines: {
                                        zeroLineColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)"
                                    },
                                    scaleLabel: {
                                        display: true,
                                        //labelString: 'x axis'
                                    },
                                    ticks: {
                                        maxRotation: 0,
                                        // Vertical labels at bottom
                                        userCallback: function(tick, value, ticks) {
                                            // `ticks` is the default display
                                            // `.split("")` makes it an array of every character
                                            // console.log("Value is " +value);
                                            return tick.split("");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }],
                                yAxes: [{
                                    gridLines: {
                                        display: true,
                                        lineWidth: 1, borderColor: '#66f',
                                        borderDash: [10, 5],
                                        color: "black"
                                    }

                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: 61263 DataSet values?

Comment: Yes, it is very detailed dataset. But values are rendered quite quickly, but not correctly.

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Comment: Yes, here is:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0akrn56/

Comment: And what type of yScale is being used in the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly You mean..Could you be more specific please?